# How to rectify the crash related to iAd in my application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, iad

I have integrated iAd in my application and i am executiong it in my simulator. I kept the target iOS 4.1. But some times I am getting the error:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString bannerViewDidLoadAd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6451cd0' " and the application will be quit. What i have to do.
```

I statically added the `ADBannerView` in interface builder and used the delegate methods like this:

```
#pragma mark ADBannerViewDelegate

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {

    Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
if(classAdBannerView!= nil)
    iAdView2.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
Class classAdBannerView = NSClassFromString(@"ADBannerView");
if(classAdBannerView!= nil)
    iAdView2.hidden = YES;
}
```

If any one know the solution please help me.

Comment: As your target is iOS 4.1, you don't need to check the existence of ADBannerView class. (Event if your target is iOS 3.x, you don't need to check in delegate methods, because delegate methods will never called if ADBannerView class doesn't exist.)

Comment: Catch the exception.  If it's not critical, and it doesn't sound like this is, ignore it or try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exception:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[NSCFString bannerViewDidLoadAd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6451cd0' "
```

Suggests that your delegate object going out of scope. It may be because you have created it in auto-release pool  or releasing it somewhere. You will need to retain it.

Thanks